# How to styling React-Select

Tags: reactjs, styling, react-select

I want to modify border on the react-select. I'm using props `className` but but what happens instead is to create a new border as a wrapper.

this my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from "react-select"

const InputSelect = (props) => {
  const { options, placeholder } = props
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      className="border border-red-500" />
  )
}

export default InputSelect
```

Result:
[image]

And then i try using `inputClassName` . But nothing happen

below this my code using `inputClassName` :

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from "react-select"

const InputSelect = (props) => {
  const { options, placeholder } = props
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      inputClassName="border border-red-500"
    />
  )
}

export default InputSelect
```

Result using `inputClassName`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `control` key to extend the border color and box shadow of `react-select` component. Spreading the provided styles into your returned object lets you extend it however you like while maintaining existing styles. You can refer [this link](https://react-select.com/styles) to style other things of component.

```js
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {hasError: false};
    }
    
    onChange = (value) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ hasError: !prevState.hasError }));
    }
    
    render() {
        const {hasError} = this.state;
        const getColor = (isValid) => isValid ? 'gray' : 'red';
        const colourStyles = {
          control: (styles) => ({ 
              ...styles, 
              borderColor: getColor(!hasError), 
              boxShadow: `0 0 0 1px ${getColor(!hasError)}`, 
              ':hover' : { 
                borderColor: getColor(!hasError), 
                boxShadow: `0 0 0 1px ${getColor(!hasError)}`,  
              } 
           })
        };
        return <Select onChange={this.onChange} styles={colourStyles} options={options} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.12.7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/classnames@2.2.6/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.2/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/emotion@10.0.27/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.4.4/dist/react-select.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how to adjust class dynamically?
e.g. I've declared ```isError```. If ```isError``` is ```true```, the border turns red. else the border becomes gray

Comment: You can pass on state and based on that change the color. I have update the solution.